# Bootstrap tagsinput not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I just came across Bootstrap tagsinput and I am trying it out, but I cant seem to get it working.

I added the following at the top of my layout :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bootstrap_tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
```

And I added the following at the bottom of my layout :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap_tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
```

Then in my partial page I added the following :

```
<input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags" class="form-control">
```

Below is an image of what is happening, instead of the tags showing:

[image]

To my understanding, this should work. What am I missing ?

Comment: Maybe not all of sources (script or css-file) are found on your web-server. Try to inspect a page by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome

Comment: what seems to be the problem.? input box not appearing? errors? can you provide a jsfiddle or image illustrating the problem

Comment: I added an image of that was happening.

Comment: Pls, give a link to your page

Comment: I would love to, but unfortunately this is on my local.

Comment: did you add jquery link.? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Tried adding it now, makes no difference. Im going to try create a new project(clean project) and see if that works, if it does, then its something thats conflicting...

Comment: Ok I created a new MVC project and still sitting with the same issue... I have now updated my bootstrap to Bootstrap 3.3.7 in the hopes that this is the issue, but still nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this links in your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

DEMO

[Bootstrap - tagsinput](http://codepen.io/dannibla/pen/QGLyBW) , [Github - Reference](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap-2.3.2.html)

Comment: Your demo is exactly what I want... I tried putting those in my PartialView and it didnt work. I also tried putting it in my Layout and it also didnt work...

Comment: I retract my previous statement. I used the examples in your Demo and I got it working! Not sure what I did wrong previously, but I obviously did something that caused it not to work. Thank you!!

Comment: @Daniel J Abraham how would you remove the comma automatically after tagging is added?

Answer (score 6):

I *think* that because it's a partial view and it appears after the library is loaded, it doesn't get applied.

I had exactly the same problem. My Index page had all the libraries included but the partial view never used them.

I had to add this to the partial view Razor to force it to apply after load.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input[data-role=tagsinput]').tagsinput();
    }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

did you initialized your input like

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'citynames',
    displayKey: 'name',
    valueKey: 'name',
    source: citynames.ttAdapter()
  }
});
```

Comment: I previously tried $('#tags').tagsInput(); and tried your suggestion above as well, but makes no difference :(

Answer (score 0):

it's because old style using bootstrap class "label label-info". Try to change into "badge badge-info" class

```
$('.tags').tagsinput({
     tagClass: 'badge badge-info'
 });
```